# Opening tab with anchor link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, anchor

As the title said, i'm trying to do this this by checking the hash when the page loads, and then trigger a click on the right tab, like so:

Javascript

```
   <script>
    $(function () {
        $(".tab-nav a").bind('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('li').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('active').hide();
    console.log($('.tab-content:eq('+$(this).index()+')'));
    $('.tab-content:eq('+$(this).parents('li').index()+')').addClass('active').show();
});

$('.tab-nav a').first().click();

var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );
if (hash) $('.tab-nav a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');

});
    </script>
```

Here's my tab setup under services.html

```
<section class="tabs">

    <ul class="tab-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#first">First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#second">Second Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#third">Third Tab</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Here's the first piece of content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content active">
        <p>My tab is active so I'll show up first! Inb4 tab 3!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Don't forget about me! I'm tab 3!</p>
    </div>

 </section>
```

And so when I link from the home page to the services page lets say the second tab:

```
<a href="services.html#second></a>
```

I'd like it to go to the second tab :)

What's the issue with my code?

Comment: there is no issue with code ,its working goto http://jsfiddle.net/wBfq4/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```
$('#mylink').click(function() {
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 1); // switch to second tab
return false;
 });
```